# Latex: includegraphics - width and height

Tags: graphics

The code below is executing properly:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{name1}
\caption{Figure 1}\label{name1}
\end{figure}
```

However when I add `width` and `height`:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=15cm,height=6cm]{name1}
\caption{Figure 1}\label{name1}
\end{figure}
```

I get this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The optional argument with key value options are added by package `graphicx`, note the `x` at the end. Package `graphics` has a different syntax and meaning of the optional arguments, from the documentation of packages `graphics` and `graphicx`, [`grfguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf):

`graphics`: `\includegraphics[`*⟨llx,lly⟩*`][`*⟨urx,ury⟩*`]{`*⟨file⟩*`}`
`graphicx`: `\includegraphics[`*⟨key val list⟩*`]{`*⟨file⟩*`}`

Solution:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\includegraphics[width=15cm, height=6cm]{name1}
```

This might distort the image, if the specifications do not hit the aspect ratio of the image. Option `keepaspectratio` scales the image down if necessary to fit the available space but without distorting the image:

```
\includegraphics[
  width=15cm,
  height=6cm,
  keepaspectratio,
]{name1}
```

Answer (score 15):

I read a lot about that and found an answer:

add `\shorthandoff{=}`  AFTER `\begin{document}`.

Edit: 
 `\includegraphics{figure.png}` always works great. But whenever I added anything else, such as  `\includegraphics[height=0.5\textwidth,angle=-90]{figure.png}`, it didn't compile. Normally it doesn't do that but that happens whenever I use `babel` package. That happens because `babel` package changes `=` sign and add some other things. That is why I needed to reset `=` by adding `\shorthandoff{=}`. At least that was what solved my problem.

Comment: You should explain (briefly) what the code does or why the code works.