# How to adjust the Size of a Plot inside a Table?

Tags: tables, plot

How can one adjust the size of the plot in the following table:

```
 \begin{longtable}{ | c | m{3cm}  | }
    \hline
    Graph & Items  \\ 
    \hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sinx}
    \end{minipage} &  \begin{itemize} \item Item 1 \item Item 2 \item Item 3 \item Item 4 \item Item 5 \item Item 6 \item Item 7 \item Item 8  \item Item 9 \item Item 10  \end{itemize}   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

The result is

[image]

EDIT: My real concern is the space above the image.

Comment: the minipage isn't doing anything, you can remove that then make the image as wide as you like with `width=.2\textwidth` or whatever you need, you can control the vertical alignment with `\raisebox` or using valign key added by adjustbox package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latex: includegraphics - width and height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234441/latex-includegraphics-width-and-height)

Comment: @SebGlav I suspect not. (despite the question title I would guess the issue is the white space above the image)

Comment: Nothing is working! Yes, the issue is the white space above the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this  MWE the position of the image can be adjusted adding a (positive or negative) vertical space.

`\vspace*{0pt}`

[image: X0]

`\vspace*{150pt}`

[image: X150]

`\vspace*{-150pt}`

[image: Xmin]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    
     \begin{longtable}{ | c | m{3cm}  | }
        \hline
        Graph & Items  \\ 
        \hline
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.3\textwidth}   
        %\vspace*{150pt}    % adjust top space      
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}                 
        \end{minipage} &
        \parbox[b]{\linewidth}
        {\begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1 
            \item Item 2 
            \item Item 3 
            \item Item 4 
            \item Item 5 
            \item Item 6 
            \item Item 7 
            \item Item 8  
            \item Item 9 
            \item Item 10
            \end{itemize}}
   \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, where should be vertical positioned image. If you like to have in the vertical middle of cells, than see the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbullet,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531952/
    after ={\end{minipage}}
                  } }

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ | m{0.3\linewidth} | m{3cm}  | }
    \hline
    Graph & Items  \\
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    &  \begin{itemize} 
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
    \item Item 3 
    \item Item 4 
    \item Item 5 
    \item Item 6 
    \item Item 7 
    \item Item 8  
    \item Item 9 
    \item Item 10  
        \end{itemize}   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like to have at top of cell, than try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,%
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbullet,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531952/
    after ={\end{minipage}}
                  } }

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{0.3\linewidth} | p{3cm}  | }
    \hline
    Graph & Items  \\
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t, margin=2pt]{example-image-duck}
    &  \begin{itemize} 
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
    \item Item 3 
    \item Item 4 
    \item Item 5 
    \item Item 6 
    \item Item 7 
    \item Item 8  
    \item Item 9 
    \item Item 10  
        \end{itemize}   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]